# push notifications using mongoose and fcm with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a social network app using node.js and as any app with this category it contains posts and I want to send a notification for all the followers of the user when a new post added.

I have fcm tokens for all users but I want to find the best way to achieve that without causing any server overloads.

I am using mongoose as orm and MongoDB as a database

Can I achieve this with fcm or should I move to twilio or any service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging).

You would have to figure out the implementation details as that is custom to your project requirements.
But on the question of if it's possible or not and server overload: I'm very sure it's possible, and by thoughtfully creating [device-groups or topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple) that allow you to send messages to multiple devices(in-a-go), there shouldn't be an overload on your servers, the FCM server should handle most of the workload. More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/fcm-architecture).